# How to access a created factory bot value in cucumber step definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I m new to factory bot and cucumber,
How to access a created record using factory_bot in step definition?
test/factories.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :signuser do
    email  'abcd1123@test.xyz'
    password   'test123'
    password_confirmation 'test123'
  end
end


#In console
FactoryBot.create(:signuser)

#features/test_step.rb

When (/^enter exists details for Register$/)do
#I want to access email "abcd1123@test.xyz" and password "test123" here in textfield
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the user in the `Given` block

```
Given /^a user with email "(.+)"$/ do |email|
  FactoryBot.create(:user, email: 'user')
end
```

And after it you can use this user in your step

```
When (/^enter exists details for Register$/)do
  fill_in 'user_email', with: User.last.email
end
```

Comment: Thank you guy ,but "Unable to find visible field "signuser_email" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)" this above error is displayed. Please help anyone

Comment: I'm a girl, not a guy :) Do you have in your view an input field with name, id or label text "signuser_email"? `fill_in` method works via fields name, id or label text, so you need to use a correct one.

Comment: Sorry, Vasilisa  In view/registration/new.html.erb    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div> When use a fill_in 'email',with:Signuser.last.email   Above same error shown